# Create a category based Subnav in opencart

Tags: navigation, opencart, categories

Heres what I am trying to do in Opencart I need to create a subnav based of only a few specific categories.

So what I think I need to do is replicate the way in which opencart handles the top nave then put in a filter for the specific categories required.

At present I have hardcoded the links I need but would rather have this dynamic so that any sub cats added in admin will populate wuthout gong into the code.

[This is the site I would like to get this working on](http://ravenspringcouk.ichost3.co.uk/)

Any ideas on how best to achive this are welcome

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by simply selecting the required values from a category to get its subcategories. Say your category ID for your subcategory parent is 5, you would do

```
<?php

$this->load->model('catalog/category');
$result = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(5);

?>
```

Then you loop through the categories (`$results`) and output them as you wish

Comment: That looks like just what I need could you elaborate on where to place the code